# Wifi cuts in Kubuntu 14.04 with RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter

Tags: wireless, kubuntu

I have a Lenovo G50 and I have a **RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter**.

I am using a **Kubuntu 14.04** and my kernel version is: **3.13.0-45-generic**

I am having some problems with the wifi. At the beginning it seems it works, but after 10-15 minutes I have cuts on my signal and the wifi doesn't work.

How can I fix that?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had been struggling with this issue for months. Here's what finally worked for me:

**Download the latest driver (you might have to install git first)**

```
git clone http://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
```

**Change into the new directory you just created**

```
cd rtlwifi_new
```

**Compile and install the new driver**

```
make
sudo make install
```

**Edit the settings for the driver**

```
echo "options rtl8723be fwlps=0 swlps=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
```

It's probably a good idea to take a look at that file to make sure that worked. Some people say the "swlps=0" part of the command above is unnecessary. I'm not sure but it doesn't seem to be hurting anything.

Reboot.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

`wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v3.18.1/backports-3.18.1-1.tar.xz`

`tar -xf backports-3.18.1-1.tar.xz`

`cd ~/backports-3.18.1-1`

`make defconfig-rtlwifi`

`make`

`sudo make install`
Reboot and enjoy wifi

Comment: After about 30 minutes I had problems again with the Wifi. I tried to do the other solution and the Wifi has worked perfectly all day.